# OpenGL billboard interpolation issue

Tags: c, macos, opengl, mipmaps

I have a billboard quad with a texture mapped onto it.

This is basically some text with transparency.

The billboard floats forwards and backwards from the camera's perspective.

As the billboard moves away (and appears smaller) there is an flickering effect
around the edges of the text where there is a stroke border on the actual texture.

I think this is because interpolation is needed as the image which is normally X pixels wide is now shown as only a % of X and some pixels need to be merged together. I guess it's doing nearest neighbour or something? Can anyone point me in the right direction for opengl settings to control this, I'm guessing there is some way of preventing this effect from happening by adjusting the method for how the texture is handled ?

I think its got something to do with:

```
GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST
```

but when i try setting this for the MIN filter and enabling mip mapping my texture becomes very blocky and blurred...

i've also tried:

```
GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR
```

which is apparently triliear filtering for the MIN filter but my image is very blurry when displayed. (looks like it is a very low res texture) any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR); // trilinear

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
```

More code:

```
// Allocated memory needed for the bitmap context
spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
// Uses the bitmap creation function provided by the Core Graphics framework. 
spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
// After you create the context, you can draw the sprite image to the context.
CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), spriteImage);
// You don't need the context at this point, so you need to release it to avoid memory leaks.
CGContextRelease(spriteContext);

// Use OpenGL ES to generate a name for the texture.
glGenTextures(1, &spriteTexture[textureCount-1]); 

// Bind the texture name. 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture[textureCount-1]);


glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);


glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);



// Specify a 2D texture image, providing the a pointer to the image data in memory
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);
// Release the image data
free(spriteData);
```

The texture is 512 x 512.

Example of the blurryness when the MIN filter is used:

[image: Blurry billboard]

When just using GL_NEAREST for the min filter sharper but nasty bilinear and the flickering as mentioned above when animated as shrinking:

[image: GL_NEAREST]

Comment: Could you show some screenshots?

Comment: Also, you need to set these parameters before you upload the texture (using `glTexImage2d` or so). That way, the mipmap will be generated when you call `glTexImage2d`. Without the rest of the code, I can't see if that's what you're doing.

Comment: What happens with plain 'ole GL_LINEAR?

Comment: blurry as well with GL_LINEAR

Comment: How does GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR look if you apply a Gaussian blur to your original 512x512 texture before uploading it?

Comment: Call glGetError after *each and every* OpenGL call. Call it continually until it returns GL_NO_ERROR. What does it say?

Comment: @genpfault I'll try but whats the intention of the test?

Comment: @PeanutPower: Hopefully to smooth out the 1px text border so it doesn't shimmer as much as it shrinks.

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you test this on? What OpenGL core version do you use? What does glGetError() report? Always remember to specify this. Also, a full testcase would be very helpful, and maybe even required for others to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using glu, I would suggest that you try using gluBuild2DMipmaps to create the mipmaps and see how others do this.

To avoid using glu functions, I sometimes look at Mesa's OpenGL implementation to get some ideas (I generally try to keep a lot of code in my own project.. and I share a lot of it between OpenGL, D3D, and other platforms).  You can try looking at the source for the [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/download.html) implementation (MesaLib) of gluBuild2DMipmaps to see how you could get a similar effect.  It appears in MesaLib's mipmap.c, and you'll probably end up jumping to the implementation of bitmapBuild2DMipmaps.

I can't guarantee that this will lead to good results, but it's an avenue to explore.  For general debugging of what's happening, another thing you could try is to output your mipmap textures to files for external viewing.  All this is of course after you've exhausted your options of randomly toggling flags and googling other peoples' code to see if you missed any state functions.

Answer (score 1):

Mipmapping is controlled by the ratio of texels to pixels for the fragments being drawn (hopefully my terminology is correct there). How large are you drawing it on screen?

If you're drawing it at (say) 128x128, you'll get mipmap level 2, hence the blur.

Textures should be created at the size they'll be shown at on screen, or as close as possible to, rather than producing too many pixels and letting the GPU pick an inappropriate mipmap level...